# Requirements to visit Italy

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, italy, applications, insurance

Greetings from Mexico.

I am planning a trip to Italy, it will be my first trip to Europe with a duration of 6 days.
 I have been researching about the requirements that I must meet in order to make this trip. I found that I do not need
 visa, but I also found that I must have international medical insurance with a minimum coverage of € 30,000 for emergency hospitalization expenses
 and repatriation costs, which I do not have. The question is: Is the **international medical insurance** really a mandatory requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find the insurance requirement?

Comment: It sounds expensive but mostly the travel insurances are sold for small amounts. Even when you do not have to have it, it is a good thing to spend money on.

Comment: €30,000 of coverage does not mean you have to pay €30,000.

Comment: @phoog I found it in a diferents web sites.

Comment: @Christian I know it. Just I want to know that if the international medical insurance is mandatory.

Comment: @YemisiSCG as far as I am aware, that requirement applies only to visa applicants, not to visa-free travelers.  Could you add a link to a specific site or two so we can address the claim directly?

Comment: Of course:  [Viajar a Italia](https://www.viajaraitalia.com/visas-y-permisos-para-ingresar-a-italia/)  [Conociendo Italia](https://www.conociendoitalia.com/requisitos-para-viajar-a-italia/)

Comment: If you have €30,000 sitting in a bank account somewhere, then you can possibly do without the travel insurance. The official rules are [here](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/stranieri/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/mezzi_finanziari), as far as I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first - if you want check the requirement for visit of Italy you can check [this link](http://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home/en) - this website officially connected with Italian international authorities. For Mexico it seems that you need only valid passport and you do not need the visa if your travel less than 90 days.
There is nothing about insurance and mainly I never heard about insurance check on the border for Italian non-residents. If you will apply for visa, yes, everywhere insurance is obligatory to make.
By the way I don't understand your problem. Mainly insurance for 30000 EUR of coverage should cost 20-30 EUR if you will travel for 1-2 weeks as tourist and it is not connected with extreme sports or skiing.
Moreover even finally you will find that it is not obligatory it is really highly recommeded to make - it is really  your insurance that you will be paid and covered if something happen. And if you think good it is not the subject to ignore.
Anyway the absence of visa between Mexico and Italy doesn't mean you can come in the way you prefer. Border control is able to request additional information about your entrance, your plan including the information about the money you have and what for you want to live and travel during your trip, where do you want to live and do you have prepaid accommodation etc.
Also I found good idea for you: many airline websites offer travel insurance at the bottom once your transaction is almost complete - you can add to your total purchase.

Comment: Insurance is indeed very important and not expensive. And a very good thing to have when things do go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that the Insurance is very important, I have one but the coverture is limited in diferents countries. Whaterver now I know that to travel to Italy is easy.